# Is "much useful" correct usage?

Tags: word-usage

How correct is this sentence:

> Your advice isn't much useful

I couldn't really find it wrong however for some reason, it is not sounding right. The sentence "*Your advice isn't very userful*." seems much more fluent.

So is the phrase much useful grammatically correct?

Many Thanks

PS: I am learning English and would appreciate if someone could point/correct any mistakes in my question.

Comment: If you're an English language learner, you might consider asking on https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions. Anyway, you are probably confused with "much use".

Comment: "userful" _is not very useful_, and definitely not fluent by any grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Much' is a quantifier for mass (non count) nouns.

'Many' is a quantifier for plural (count) nouns.

'Very' is an intensifier for adjectives.

'Use' is a verb or noun.  'Useful' is an adjective.  'Usefulness' is a noun.

So "your advice isn't [of] much use", or "your advice isn't very useful."